# Oganize kotlin project with Kotlin web server and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

I have this question because i was a PHP developer before and all of my project is run in apache server.

I’m newbee or Kotlin languague. I want learn Kotlin via create a project. Now I want create a project use Kotlin web server (may be use ktor framework). I want use this with react kotlin like https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app to build my front end. How can i oganize my project to build that ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out as well. The command itself structures your project to do this. See the readme documentation on the github page:

https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app

You should have to run `npx create-react-kotlin-app my-app` but you will also some additional setup according to the docs.

If you are looking for a fullstack example, there is one here that uses react:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-fullstack-sample

I also found this Spring example here:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

The Spring example actually uses Java, but you can just initialize your project with Kotlin instead.

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the documentation that's relevant to the question in the answer itself. This helps stop this part of your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working for whatever reason.

Comment: Back again to remind you to please include context around any links you include in your answer! Links should be used to supplement any information you provide in the answer itself, and answers that are little more than links may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). You should check out the [answer] article in the [help] for some good tips on writing a good-quality answer.